# How Can I Get C# To Distinguish Between Ambiguous Class Names?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I get C# to distinguish between ambiguous class types without having to specify the full `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument` name every time (it is ambiguous compared to `System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument`)?

Is there a way to make C# know that I am ALWAYS talking about one class or the other, and thus not have to specify it each time I use it?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use aliases:

```
using HapHtmlDocument = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument;
using WfHtmlDocument = System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument;
```

Answer (score 8):

You can define an alias for one namespace, e.g:

```
using hap = HtmlAgilityPack;
```

and then use the alias instead of the full namespace:

```
hap.HtmlDocument doc = new hap.HtmlDocument;
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare conflicting namespaces at different levels, most inner one will be used without ambiguity:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyNamespace {
    using HtmlAgilityPack;

    public class Class1 {
        private HtmlDocument _doc; // HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    }
```