# Ambiguous reference between two namespaces

Tags: asp.net, .net, linq

I am getting the following error

> Error 36  'SLICDataContext' is an ambiguous reference between
>   'SLIC_DataAccess.SLICDataContext' and
>   'SLIC_DataAccess.Generic.SLICDataContext'
>   CreateRequest.aspx.cs 48  36  C:...

Code:

```
int num = (
    from x in (new SLICDataContext()).ClientsToPriorities
        where x.PriorityID == Convert.ToInt32(this.drpPriority.SelectedValue)
        where x.ClientID == this.GetClientID
    select x.ClientToPriorityID).Single<int>();
return num;
```

Namespaces I am using

```
using SLIC_DataAccess.Generic;
using SLIC_DataAccess;
```

How can I be more specific in referencing the namespaces in my code to resolve this?

Comment: It looks like you have two classes with the same name, but in two different namespaces. Regarding your namespace names, I wonder if there is not a problem at a higher level. Is it autogenerated code? if yes, is the generation properly set? Can't you rename either of the two classes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Can I Get C# To Distinguish Between Ambiguous Class Names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427346/how-can-i-get-c-sharp-to-distinguish-between-ambiguous-class-names)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fully qualify your class in your code using the applicable namespace.

Depending on the implementation, it will be one of these:

```
from x in (new SLIC_DataAccess.Generic.SLICDataContext()).ClientsToPriorities
```

or

```
 from x in (new SLIC_DataAccess.SLICDataContext()).ClientsToPriorities
```

Another option would be to use aliases as follows:

```
using SLIC_DA_Generics = SLIC_DataAccess.Generic;
using SLIC_DA = SLIC_DataAccess;
```

with the appropriate usage as follows:

```
from x in (new SLIC_DA_Generics.SLICDataContext()).ClientsToPriorities
```

or

```
from x in (new SLIC_DA.SLICDataContext()).ClientsToPriorities
```

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly say which namespace you wish to use, for example:

```
from x in (new SLIC_DataAccess.Generic.SLICDataContext()).ClientsToPriorities
```